# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005, mssql-jdbc

I have one more issues. and it giving only in MSSQL server:

```
select theme0_.id as id12_, theme0_.user as user12_, theme0_.theme as theme12_ 
from theme theme0_ where theme0_.user=1
```

This query is giving error :

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.

But the query executes properly in MySQL server. Please help me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

That's because `USER` is a [Reserve Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) in `SQL Server` and needs to be escaped in query using square bracket `[]`.

Whereas that's not the case for [MySQL Reserve Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Your query should look like

```
select [id] as id12_, 
[user] as user12_, 
[theme] as theme12_ 
from theme 
where [user] = 1
```